# Object becomes invisible after I join them

Tags: modeling, objects, object-mode

So I joined 2 objects together and now they are invisible. You can see them in edit mode and in Texture painting but they become invisible in object mode.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pressing Alt+H to unhide all objects?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't work.

Comment: You can upload your file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so that someone can try to find the issue.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vmD4ZeQj

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change display type from Bounds to **Textured** under *Properties editor > Object Properties > Viewport Display > Display as ...*

[image]
[image]